# Fixing bad sectors of hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a laptop that has stopped working and after a time of testing and debugging I found that the hard drive has malfunctioned.

Specifically, I have used Sea Tools for DOS and discovered that the hard has "bad sectors". The Sea Tools application has an option to try to fix this but could not fix them.

I have also used a few other diagnosing tools that found problems with the disk. Specifically, I have used one tool that analyzed the whole disk and found many unresponsive sectors (over 20) among the sectors that were responding well.

Is there a way to make the disk functional ? Is there a way to fix or remove them from use ?

Edit: I have tried different application to format the disk but they do not work. They return an error that there is a problem with the disk.

Comment: It depends on filesystem you're using. You may mark those bad blocks, so that system wouldn't use them. But it's not wise storing any non-expendable data on that disk.

Comment: @week, can you explain with a little more detail about filesystem and how bad sectors can be marked ?

Comment: @AncientRo your hdd does that automatically you can't fix bad sectors only move the data again happens automatically at this point replacement is advised there will be a time the hdd cannot recover the data on the bad sectors to move the data or simply no spare sectors to move to

Comment: If you're using Windows than you can run `chkdsk /R` utility, that'll check disks partition for bad sectors and avoid further using those.

Comment: @week I am in DOS and running these testing and diagnosis applications from DOS. I cannot install an operating system nor can I format the drives.

Comment: @Ramhound I am in DOS and the hdd does not automatically ignore the bad sectors when I try to format or install an OS. When I try to format it says that it cannot format because there is a problem with the disk. When I try to install an OS it interrupts at one point when it cannot copy certain files.

Comment: Try to use `quick format`, that should avoid checking for bad blocks, then you may run `chkdsk /R` for marking those blocks.

Comment: That means the device cannot repair the number of errors that exist

Comment: @week Like I have mentioned, I am in DOS not Windows.

Comment: You can perform a quick format using DOS but you can boot into WinPE or any number of better tools.

Comment: @Rambound I have tried quick format. NTFS returns a problem with the hard, FAT works. After a quick FAT format, when I try to install the OS, it breaks at some point when it can no longer copy files. I have also tried other format application, PartitionMagic in DOS that returns errors with the disk both for NTFS and FAT.

Comment: Sledgehammer time... Best fix on a dead drive as you then can quit wasting time on it. It's like having a 500,000 mile rustbucket car that has all 4 gears stripped out of the trans, the engine has punched a rod through the side of the block and the left rear axle broke, the right front wheelbearing spun and welded to the axle stub, and the packing crate you were using to cover the foot square hole in the floor boards just rotted through. Jack up the radiator cap and drive a new car underneath. When drives are in this shape...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make them functional again, in fact it is the disk itself that detects the bad sectors and takes them out of use. There is a reserve of sectors that are not used when the disk is new that take over from sectors that are marked as bad. There is no need to manually remove sectors from use.

You use to have to manually mark sectors as bad within the filesystem, but unless this disk is ancient (more than 15 years old) that isn't the case for you.

That said, disks with bad sectors are usually going bad and will gain more and more bad sectors over time. Every bad sector is lost data. I would suggest immediately backing up any data and replacing the disk.

Comment: Last paragraph is probably the most important one. After few first bad sectors, next ones will start to appear. This disk isn't safe for storage anymore, it's a ticking timebomb for your data.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Replace the disk ***immediately!*** If you have problems recovering data from the disk, there are tools that may enable at least partial recovery, but the most important action right now is to get as much data off the disk as soon as possible.